# python - pythonic way to check assignment and exit if None

Tags: python, coding-style, nonetype

I was looking for a python analogous of (C)

```
 if ((p = malloc(N * sizeof(*p))) == NULL) return 1;
```

Something like `user = getUser() or return` does not work nor would `if (user = getUser() is None) return` - what's the pythonic way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to assign and check the assigned value in one go, there isn't one, and Python dissuades you from creating one.

```
user = get_user()
if user is None:
    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [context management](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) under two conditions:

- The `get_user()` return a class type you can tweak
- You are willing to define two special functions in the class returned by `get_user`, namely

  ```
  __enter__(self)
  __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback)
  ```

Now, lets suppose your `User` class is all set and ready, then you could write the following

```
with get_user() as user:
    # do what you need to do
```

So this way the assignment happened in the `with` statement which calls your special methods upon entering and exiting the context management scope. Inside those methods you can specify the checks and the behavior uppon failure or success to comply with your specifications